# Possible to upgrade PowerShell 2.0 to 3.0 without a reboot?

Tags: powershell, installation, powershell-v3.0

Is it possible to upgrade powershell without reboot from 2.0 to 3.0 using Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing the WMF 3.0 (KB2506143 or KB2506146 depending on current OS version) even on a server that already has .NET 4.0, **requires a reboot.**